# Turning Existing Eccommerce Site into Multi-SIte

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, multisite, e-commerce

I have an existing multi-site that is a pretty in-depth e-commerce (woo) site with lots of features (free-shipping, discounts, memberships.) I need to create a sub-brand for an existing product, leveraging the existing theme and functionality.

I figured the best way to turn the existing site into a multi-site. Am guessing some plugins I will have to buy different licenses etc. But mainly am afraid that all the functionality will break on the existing site, is this true? has anyone had experience with something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I develop locally in a non-multi-site environment, then push to a multi-site (not the users or user_meta tables). Most plugins will work, but some expressly do not, so you should check with each first. This workflow was used on a WooCommerce site with no issues. Get comfortable with the table structure differences between standard and multi-site and make backups before proceeding, too.

Comment: ok thanks! the site's already live, so you aside from certain plugins, you don't think there will be an issue turning the existing site into multi-site? if I create a new site from existing multi-site, it shouldn't copy over users or anything like that right?